# How can I make an instance run in another process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a simple code that creates an instance that calls a global function every minute. I'd like to make the instance run in another process, so that a scheduler in the instance can run in loop, even after the main process ends. How can I do that? Is it possible to have an instance, not a function, run in another process?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def sendSignal():
    print('Signal sent')

class signalScheduler():
    global sendSignal

    def __init__(self):
        self.sched = BackgroundScheduler()
        self.sched.start()
        self.sched.add_job(sendSignal, trigger='cron', minute='*/1')

sigSched = signalScheduler()
```

Comment: What do you mean by an instance *being run* in another process?

Comment: @bogdanciobanu Thank you for your comment! If I setup apscheduler in a function and make it run in another process, the scheduler doesn't work in loop because the function eventually exits. But if I setup apscheduler in an instance, it runs in loop. That's what I mean by an instance being run in a process.

Comment: _**calls a global function every minute**_, `apscheduler` isn't intended to do so. Use `multiprocessing.Timer`